# Stock Android phone in 2017

Tags: android, smartphones

I'm looking for a new Android phone to replace my current Nexus 5.
It should be similar in size (the Nexus 5 is 137.8 by 69.2 mm, so a **screen diagonal of about 5 inches**) - I don't like the trend towards large phones. I am however looking for **decent hardware**.
It should also come with an **unmodified current version of Android**, I also don't like waiting for months/years for updates as I had to in the past with a phone from LG. I'd prefer for it to have an **audio jack** and the **navbar buttons on-screen**, not as hardware buttons. Another thing bugging me about my Nexus 5 is that it only has 16 GB of storage - I need **32 GB at the very least**.

Comment: Have a look at the Nokia 5, the Nokia 6, the Nokia 8 and the upcoming Nokia 7. And reports claim that they sometimes get the monthly updates before the pixel devices and that they run an even more pure Android than Google devices.

Comment: Can a phone run purer android than the Google Pixel?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the 32GB model of the [Motorola Moto G5](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g5-8454.php)

All Motorola phones come with as clean android as you are going to find on the market (compared to the Google Pixel) and they have very good hardware specifications, check in the link above.

Its screen size is 5 inches, the only hardware button is the home button, and it has an audio jack. Decent camera too.