# In 2022, which phone is the closest to Stock Android? i.e. What surpassed Android One?

Tags: android, smartphones

Android One was a program that featured a list of phones with Stock Android. But since the program has been pretty much dead since 2021, which phone can replace it?

That is, which phone nowadays is closest to Stock Android?

This is a more general question than 2017's [Stock Android phone](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8018/stock-android-phone/8019),

Answer (score 1):

Although the current answer is correct, it is missing 2 very important names: Google Pixel and Fairphone. Both of these phone manufacturers put really close to stock android on their phones. One bonus with the Fairphone is that it is easily repairable, and I've also heard it is also easy to flash with even cleaner android (or less clean android if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Most Motorola phones and Nokia phones have near-stock Android experience.
Phone companies like Sony, Asus also have few models featuring stock UI.

Comment: How can you recognize those few models?

Comment: Watch Tech Spurt channel on youtube and check out this article. https://www.androidauthority.com/best-smartphones-stock-android-844672/